# Android Live Stream Application

Tags: android, video-streaming, live-streaming, android-developer-api

can anyone gives me some tips about How to make live Stream application in android 
I have search a lot but I didn't find any suitable SDK or APIs that helps me in this purpose.
Simply I need to make an android app to record a video and live stream it on webpage or website

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the "record a video and live stream" refers to having a web cam and encode it to videos and then you wish to play the streamed video on android, if yes, here are a few links that might be helpful:

- [Android: How to play RTMP video streams](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2015/09/20/android-how-to-play-rtmp-video-streams/)
- [Android: How to play RTSP or HLS video streams](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2015/09/19/android-how-to-play-rtsp-or-hls-video-streams/)

You can use [Adobe Media Encoder CC](http://www.adobe.com/hk_en/products/media-encoder.html) (free) to generate the live stream.

Comment: No I need to live broadcast a video from my application like younow.com website but on Android mobile